# Java Logging - Wrapper?

Tags: java, logging

I am starting with a new Project and have done some considerations about logging. I always used the pattern where every class, in which logging is done, has its own static Logger:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);
```

I do not really like this approach as I have to copy this line into every class where I will log something. I considered using the Android approach where there is the Log class with it's static methods to log. I started searching on the internet for a similar approach done by someone else, but did not find anything.

So my question is: What could be disatvantages of this approach?

I cannot think of any but rather of some advantages, as it follows the DRY pattern. The different categories could be handled as in Android with 'tags', which are parameters of the static Log methods.  For example:

```
 Log.debug(tag, message, exception);
```

The Log class itself would then use a common Logging Framework such as Log4j or even SLF4J.

So I am interested in your opinions.

Comment: FWIW , Play framework 2 uses a similar approach.

Comment: "[...] it follows the DRY pattern"? Au contraire! Your suggested approach forces you to always specify a tag, whereas retrieving a logger for the class (or category) in a static final variable does specify it only once. What when you decide to change the category?

Comment: Yeah, that could be a point. But what if you would log a statement for another tag? Considering that tags are not only used to specify the class where the log is placed, but maybe a subsystem of the system. So you may want to bundle some logs of subsystems made across multiple classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [java.util.logging.Logger API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger(java.lang.String)) and [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150218030827/http://hanoo.org/index.php?article=how-to-generate-logs-in-java), the main reason for `getLogger()` is to ensure the same `Logger` and `Handler` set are used independently between subsystems.

Java's recommended solution is to obtain the `Logger` at the top of each file, and then log to that object every time you need to.

Using a static `Log.debug` would require `tag` to be processed *each time* so that the correct `Handler` set was being used. Thus, it would be less efficient than having the Log object ready to go.

However, if you are not using `handlers`, or not differentiating between subsystems, then static functions would be a reasonable shortcut, so long as the library used suited your needs.